# Objective-C data type issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not that strong with Objective-C, so this is probably a simple issue.  I cannot understand why the the last line in the error completion block is causing an exception:

```
- (void)sendInappropriateNewsfeedComment:(NSString *)comment newsfeedEventId:(NSString *)newsfeedEventId completion:(void (^)(NSString *, NSInteger))completion error:(void (^)(NSString *, NSInteger))error {
    PAInappropriateNewsFeedRequest *inappropriateNewsfeedRequest = [[PAInappropriateNewsFeedRequest alloc] initWithComment:comment newsfeedEventId:newsfeedEventId];
    [inappropriateNewsfeedRequest executeWithCompletionBlock:^(id obj) {
        completion(@"SUCCESS", (NSInteger)1);
    } error:^(NSError *e, id obj) {
        NSString * message = [obj objectForKey:@"message"];

        error(message, [obj integerForKey:@"code"]);
    }];
}
```

I've also attached a screenshot showing that the "obj" object has a key called "code" that is of type "(long)-1".

[image: debug console]

What is the proper way to declare the error block and pass the "-1" value back to the call site?

Comment: Does `NSDictionary` even respond to `integerForKey:`? I'm surprised that doesn't raise an error itself. The problem here is that primitive values like `int`, `long`, `NSInteger`, etc. aren't objects (their memory is stored in-line, rather than in a heap allocated object that conforms to the memory layout that Objective C expects of objects). You need to use an object that models your number, namely, `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because `NSDictionary` has no method called `integerForKey`. That's what "unrecognized selector" means. Selector is basically a method name.

The fact that this can be even compiled is caused by using `id` for the parameter type. You can call anything on `id` but it will crash your app if the method does not exist. You should cast `obj` to a proper type as soon as possible.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) obj;
NSString *message = dictionary[@"message"];
NSNumber *code = dictionary[@"code"];
```

If `obj` can be a different type, you should make sure to check `[obj isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.self]` before casting.

Comment: Still, how do you define the error block and properly pass back the -1 value?

Answer (score 0):

The whole solution taking Sulthan's suggestions into account might looks something like this

```
typedef void (^NewFeedCompletion)(NSString *, NSInteger);
typedef void (^NewsFeedError)(NSString *, NSInteger);

- (void) sendInappropriateNewsfeedComment: (NSString *)comment
                          newsfeedEventId: (NSString *)newsfeedEventId
                               completion: (NewFeedCompletion) completion
                                    error: (NewsFeedError) error
{
    PAInappropriateNewsFeedRequest *inappropriateNewsfeedRequest = [[PAInappropriateNewsFeedRequest alloc] initWithComment:comment newsfeedEventId:newsfeedEventId];

    [inappropriateNewsfeedRequest executeWithCompletionBlock: ^(id obj) {
        completion(@"SUCCESS", (NSInteger)1);
    } error:^(NSError *e, id obj) {
        assert([obj isKindOfClass: NSDictionary.class])

        NSDictionary *errorDictionary = (NSDictionary *) obj;
        NSString *message = [errorDictionary objectForKey: @"message"];
        NSNumber *code = [errorDictionary objectForKey: @"code"]

        error(message, [code integerValue]);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Although... now that I notice it.  If you have any control over the "error" block for `ecuteWithCompletionBlock` It seems a little silly to send an `NSError` *and* an error dictionary as `NSError` has  a domain, code, and userInfo dictionary - so everything could just be in that `NSError`.